# Error Containing Character Appearences And Dialogue

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

[image: Messed up Texture]

So I've downloaded Bloodmoon - Call of the Werebeasts mod onto Xbox One, Skyrim Remastered, and I'm having an issue with the quest npcs looking like this, as you can see compared to Serana they are pixelated and multicolored. Also, I cannot interact with them, when pressing `A`, all I get is "hmm" or "well hello" even if they have a quest marker no conversation can be started! I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the mod to no avail, I've changed the load order and deleted half of my other mods that may have caused any problems, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what the downvotes are for, but we need to know what other mods you have installed, if any.

Comment: Do they work without the mod?

Comment: I currently have rich merchants of skyrim, immersive citizens, phenderix magic evolved, ultimate horse travel and sjel bald castle, and it's only the npcs for the bloodmoon quests that are like this!

Comment: Immersive citizens would be my guess. Bloodmoon NPC's may have an additional mesh that it uses that is adding or getting blocked from Immersive citizens. This usually happens when multiple meshes are covering each other and the color gets messed up.

Comment: Thanks! I'll disable immersive citizens and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Phenderix does this for me, faces all pixelated with lines through them. And conversations can't usually be started either. Perhaps it caused the bug with that mod?

Comment: Not an answer :)